# Mysql with updating the table by fetching details from joining other 2 table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i have 3 tables as

```
 imr_master table               installation table 

 mobile_nbr | imr_nbr           imr_nbr | last_reading_nbr | avg_reading_nbr

snap_log table
mobile_nbr | previous_reading_nbr | particular dates
```

Now my requirement goes like updating the installation table of particular imr_nbr with today's previous_reading_nbr from snap_log table and details of particular mobile_nbr fetched by installation & imr_master .

```
update installation a join imr_master b on a.imr_nbr=b.imr_nbr  join snap_log c on b.mobile_nbr=c.mobile_nbr
set a.last_reading_nbr = c.previous_reading_nbr AND a.average_consumption_qty=avg(c.previous_reading_nbr);
```

if i use above i'm throwing with error Invalid use of group .

Comment: Which field you are updating?only 1 field a.last_reading_nbr or 2 fields??

Comment: Yeah Charvee , It's actually 2 fields, that will be a.last_reading_nbr and a.average_consumption_qty

Comment: then replace "and" with ","

Comment: tried Charvee , still i'm getting same error

Comment: Which error you are getting??

Comment: Well , it will be "Invalid use of group function"

Comment: ok this error is coming because you are using avg function.If possible try to avoid it.

Comment: But i actually want to find out the average of particular column's data with respect to imr_nbr,

Comment: try to use `inline view`

Comment: Super, my half of the problem is solved but i actually need to find the average of previous_meter_reading from snap_log table for particular mobile_nbr

Comment: yeah thank you soo much charvee for helping me out

Comment: Thank you Pohh . Will give a try on that for sure